# Are there any pagers that use emacs keybindings?

Tags: unix, emacs, pager

Both more and less seem to be heavily influenced by the vi commands. Are there any pagers that are more emacs like out of the box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`less` supports actually a subset of both `vi` and `emacs` commands. You should be able to add the ones you are missing using the `lesskey` command.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a pager, but [GNU Info](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info/) uses the same bindings as Emacs.

Though I wonder why you would need a pager if you use Emacs…

Emacs can browse man pages with `woman`, you can « tail » a file with `auto-revert-tail-mode`.

Comment: You use pagers for a lot more than man and info pages...

Comment: My shell run in emacs and if I need to do complex operations on the output, I can simply put it in a buffer and write some elisp, run some shell command (`M-|`) or use some keyboard macros (`C-x k (`). Thus I only use a pager when I'm don't have (my) emacs.

Comment: Which shell are you using? I guess I could force myself to do more things within emacs. I already do do a lot of things. I'm just so used to using an xterm I guess...

Comment: I use multi-term to run multiple terminals inside emacs. https://github.com/daimrod/Emacs-config/blob/master/config-multi-term.el And then, you can switch between `term-char-mode` and `term-line-mode` with respectively `C-c C-k` and `C-c C-j`. `term-char-mode` has the `standard` term bindings, and with `term-line-mode` you can navigate in the buffer like in any other buffers.

Comment: I've used multi-term in the past, but stopped for some reason--not sure why, but perhaps it's time to try again. My config is here: https://github.com/apgwoz/emacs-config

Answer (score 0):

I use this bash function to view files (from memory):

```
ev() {
  emacs "$1" -nw --eval '(setq buffer-read-only t)'
}
```

It opens the file `$1` in a read only buffer.
I don't know the best way to set a bash function as a pager, I suppose you could put it in a shellscript instead and use that as pager instead.

(Not on a computer with bash to test on)

Comment: Yeah, it'd be trivial to convert this to a shell script. I'd probably use emacsclient though to avoid the hefty startup time.

Comment: or add `-Q` - that also reduces the startup time quite a bit by not loading any customizations or distro-provided packages.